# Git merge the middle commit in a branch

Tags: git

This is my current repo.

```
Z(master)---A---B---C---D(branch A)
           \
            ---E---F(branch B)
```

I want to merge commit A to master, can anyone advise how to do that?

(desired)

```
Z---A(master)---B---C---D(branch A)
     \
      ---E---F(branch B)
```

**EDIT:**

The advance of base to branch B from A to B is my typo. Please disregard it. Sorry for the confusing! Even I still learn a trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Z` is the last commit on `master`, a simple `git merge SHA1(A)` will fast-forward master HEAD to `A`.

However, to advance branchB starting from B (I know, it was a typo in your question), you will need to:

```
git branch tmp SHA(B)
git checkout branchB
git rebase tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, just like:

```
git reset master A
```

BUt only, if the structure is like ths>

```
<old>---Z<master>A---B---C---D<A>
                      \
                       \
                        \
                         E---F<B>
```

Afterwards it's like this:

```
<old>---Z---A<master>B---C---D<A>
                      \
                       \
                        \
                         E---F<B>
```

Elsewhere, correct your tree please.

Answer (score 1):

You use *git merge* to merge new changes into a branch. So while you have **master** checked out

```
$ git checkout master
```

you simply merge *B*.

```
$ git merge B
```

For *B* above, simply use the hash of that commit, or name it with A~3 or similar.

This will fast-forward **master** to include all commits up to *B*.